# Which is the better way to create access policies for a Role in Apache Shiro

Tags: java, shiro

I am working with Apache Shiro security framework and I have to apply different access policies to Roles (like effectiveFrom date which means this role is active only after a specific date).

And given the API, the best way i could achieve this was to overinding the protected USER_ROLES_QUERY query string to return me only the roles that have comply with this "effectiveFrom" date.

And I added this "effectiveFrom" field to ROLES_PERMISSIONS table.

Is there any other more effective way to achieve this?

Comment: I assume you're using a custom realm to handle this? Your realm should be able to validate the roles with the current date and effective dates.

Comment: yes, I have created a custom realm to support this policy, where I have overriden the USER_ROLES_QUERY sql query in order to take this new field from the USER_ROLES table.

Comment: Do you expect sessions to be long-lived enough that roles should change during a session, or is it ok for users to log out before updating roles? Your plan sounds ok, except for implementing some sort of cache and not making the SQL query every time.

Comment: the roles can change during a session, but the policies should not change during this time. Another think, this policies should be consider plain resources as roles, subjects and permissions.

Comment: what I have done, described above, it's basically a hack, so that's why I am looking for a cleaner solution.